# Ajax Jquery .load function not working in Internet explorer 9

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9

My preview.php file which uses a watermark plugin is not loading correctly in IE 9, when I click the load button. It works well with other browsers. I am generally having these browser compatibility issues with Jquery. How can I handle them.
I have a posthttp2.php file

```
   <html>
   <body>
   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="preview3.php">

   <input id="button" type="button" value="load"/>
   </form>
   <div id="feedback"> </div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js" > </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax3.js" > </script>

   </body>
   <html>

   And the Ajax file is ajax3.js

    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#button').click(function() {

   $('#feedback').load("preview3.php");
    });

    )};



  I have a preview.php file

  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
  <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>JQuery Image Watermark</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/proj.css" rel="stylesheet" />

     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jss/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jss/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jss/jquery-watermarker-0.3.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        div.watermark
        {
            border:1px dashed #000;
        }
        img.watermark:hover{
            cursor:move;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<!--
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#watermarked').Watermarker({
                watermark_img:      'a.png',
                onChange:           showCoords
            });
        });
        function showCoords(c)
        {
            $('#x').val(c.x);
            $('#y').val(c.y);
            $('#w').val(c.w);
            $('#h').val(c.h);
            $('#a').val(c.opacity);
        };
     //-->
        </script>
       </head>
    <body>



    <h1>Image Watermark !</h1>
    <br />
    X: <input type="text" id="x" name="x" value="" style="width:30px;" />
    Y: <input type="text" id="y" name="y" value="" style="width:30px;" />
    W: <input type="text" id="w" name="w" value="" style="width:30px;" />
    H: <input type="text" id="h" name="h" value="" style="width:30px;" />
    A: <input type="text" id="a" name="a" value="" style="width:30px;" />
    <hr />

    <img src="1.jpg" id="watermarked" />
    <br />
    Opacit&eacute;: <div id="sliderdiv" style="width:200px;"></div>
    <br />
    <br />
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: I think you are missing a `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the first page.. this puts IE into quirks mode

Comment: It also may help to use a newer version of jquery that was released closer to the release date of IE9. More than likely your issue has to do with using document.ready in the loaded script to assume your code would run in the proper order. The problem with that assumption is that the code will run from top to bottom, and since the document is already ready, the code will run before the html after it has been added.

Comment: Have you done any debugging, such as changing $(el).load to $.ajax to inspect the response text and error response text?

Answer (score 0):

actually if that is the exact code, you're missing your closing HTML tag and yes you should have a proper doctype defined:

first html document code:

```
<html>
```

should be:

```
</html>
```